# Excel 2010 select each cell in a row, activate them one by one

Tags: excel, vba

I have an XML file that I drop into Excel to make it automatically generate a table. First column(A) has a name, and the second column(B) has a date. There are a few more columns, but those are not relevant to this question.

So it looks like this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Now there is a very idiotic bug in Excel (2010). When I have the Data column, I set its property to be Dates. But Excel does not understand they are dates now. But if I double click in a cell to activate it, at that point it starts to understand its a date... strange bug, but I have to to this for each cell.

Now what I was thinking, is to have some macro or something, that activates each cell (if there is content) one after another in the B column.

Now, I don't have a clue how I can do this in the build in VBA of Excel.

Is there someone out here that could help me? I can imagine it would only need a handful of lines to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub MacroTest()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    LastRangeRow = Cells.Find("*", after:=Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Set Rng = Range("Sheet1!B2:B" & LastRangeRow)

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
       c.Select
       SendKeys "{F2}", True
       SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
       Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Next

    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It is great this works for the OP. Any explanation for what is being corrected?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what caused the 'problem' in the first place...I've experienced the same problem before and googled it. The only answer that popped up was the fact that when you format a cell as one type and then change that format, Excel does not always recognize the format. When you double click Excel suddenly recognizes it...

With this code I just simulated the double click and that solved the issue...

Answer (score 4):

Highlight column B / click Data / Text to Columns / select Delimited / click Finish (without a delimiter selected).

That should do it.

Comment: Before selecting "Delimited" you can go "Next" and specify the new format for the column explicitly. I always use this same method.

Comment: Quick and no need for VBA, Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this before - in the Formula's Ribbon > Calculation Box > Calculation Options drop down check to make sure 'Automatic' is selected.  Usually when 'Manual' is selected mass formatting changes like that wont take effect unless you manually refresh cell (i.e. select and press enter)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing ist to just run a calculation on the respective cells:

=A1-0

And the copy & paste the values :-)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096636/excel-2010-select-each-cell-in-a-row-activate-them-one-by-one#13845053) actually offers an easier way ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
Sub makeDate()
Dim rAn As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0: Application.EnableEvents = 0: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  For Each rAn In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rAn.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    rAn = Trim(rAn.Text)
    rAn = DateValue(rAn)
  Next rAn
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1: Application.EnableEvents = 1: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears you have AutoCorrect working for or against you. If you notice the small blue triangle in the bottom of row 20. Although smart tags were discontinued in 2010, so it may be this is not be your situation.

This is the [Offce Link regarding AutoCorrect Buttons](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-are-those-buttons-and-triangles-in-my-cells-HA010343018.aspx?CTT=1#BMthe_autocorrect_options_button) 
In Preferences>Proofing>AutoCorrect Options>Actions you may control additional actions and whether Excel is trying to correct your date input. I don't have a sample of your data to test with, but fiddling in those preferences may get excel to not help so much.