# Code to click in and out of a lot of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am not a coder, and new to this group. I stole the code below shamelessly from the posting here: [Excel 2010 select each cell in a row, activate them one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096636/excel-2010-select-each-cell-in-a-row-activate-them-one-by-one?newreg=db8edd5255834c7fa02f568b4048f581)

I'm having a problem though. I have a bunch of pasted formulas as text that I need to, essentially, click in and out of in order to make them formulas (can explain why I did i this way if needed). The code works great. However, it won't process through the whole document. It usually stops after 1000 lines or so.

What I need it to do is click in and out all the rows in Column D that have data in it (in this case, through D42000). Here is the current version of the code I've tried:

`

```
Sub clickinout()
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
```

Set Rng = Range("Sheet3!D1:d42000")

For Each c In Rng.Cells

```
    c.Select
    SendKeys "{F2}"
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
```

Next

End Sub
'

I've tried several variations of this, but same result. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (a) Are you getting bored while it is running and clicking into another application while the macro runs in the background?  That would cause the keystrokes to be sent to the other application.  (b) If you aren't getting bored, possibly Excel is.  Try putting a `DoEvents` inside your loop.  (c) If all your formulae start with an "=" and none of the evaluated values do, you could use `If Left(c.Value,1)="=" Then c.Formula = c.Value` to convert the current text value to be a formula, thus avoiding `SendKeys`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! The following code worked great: 'Sub clickinout()
Sheets("Sheet3").Select

Set Rng = Range("Sheet3!d1:d42000")

For Each c In Rng.Cells

        If Left(c.Value, 1) = "=" Then c.Formula = c.Value

Next

Range("D1").Select

End Sub'

Comment: It might be best if you pasted that code in as a "self-answer".  That way, if anyone else has a similar issue in the future, and go searching for a solution, they will possibly find your question and the associated answer.  (If I don't see an answer within a day or two, I'll post it as an answer myself.)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of converting values such as `"=A1"` to the formula `=A1` would be

```
Sub clickinout()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D1:D42000").Cells
        If Left(c.Value, 1) = "=" Then
            c.Formula = c.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```